# Switch to EN keyboard layout on Ubuntu login screen after each logout

Tags: keyboard-layout, logout

Is there some solution to setup default EN keyboard layout for each Ubuntu logout?

Comment: @pomsky is strange not optimal solution to add another user to fix that

Comment: You don't need to add another user to edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you achieve that if you only have the `us` layout in `/etc/default/keyboard`.